# Signature generation in Amazon S3 using Javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, xml-signature

I am trying to send a PUT request to an Amazon compatible storage, and I keep getting the following error:

```
"<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Secret Access Key and signing method. For more information, see REST Authentication and SOAP Authentication for details.</Message><RequestId>0af9f985:155f11613d1:1732:13</RequestId></Error>"
```

Can someone please tell me how to generate the correct signature using the Secret Access Key and other parameters, in Javascript. I know that I am using the correct credentials, because all other operations supported by Amazon S3 are working, using the Amazon S3 SDK. I went through this link:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html, but I couldn't find what the method is expecting for each parameters.

Adding the code, that I have written. This is pretty much the same as you see in the Javascript SDK, only the method `canonicalizedResource`, is more simpler:

```
    private stringToSign(request: any) {
        var parts = [];
        parts.push(request.headers['method']);
        parts.push(request.headers['Content-MD5'] || '');
        parts.push(request.headers['Content-Type'] || '');
        parts.push(request.headers['presigned-expires'] || '');

        var headers = this.canonicalizedAmzHeaders(request);
        if (headers) parts.push(headers);
        parts.push(this.canonicalizedResource(request));
        return parts.join('\n');;
    }

    private canonicalizedAmzHeaders(request: any) {
        var amzHeaders = [];
        AWS.util.each(request.headers, function(name) {
            if (name.match(/^x-amz-/i))
                amzHeaders.push(name);
        });
        amzHeaders.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.toLowerCase() < b.toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1;
        });
        var parts = [];
        AWS.util.each(amzHeaders, function(name) {
            parts.push(amzHeaders[name].toLowerCase() + ':' + request.headers[amzHeaders[name]]);
        });
        return parts.join('\n');
    }

    private canonicalizedResource(request) {

        return request.path || '/';
    }
```

I call the method like:

```
var signature = this.sign(AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey, this.stringToSign(request));
```

Comment: Can you also paste the code you are using to generate the signature?

Comment: Please find the code, in the question description. -Thanks.

Comment: "an Amazon compatible storage?"  Not actually S3? The Signature Version 4 algorithm has a [test suite](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-test-suite.html) that not only provides you with sample credentials, requests, and results, but also intermediate values to help focus your troubleshooting to help you find what is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure your system time is up to date? I have had issues when my system time is out of sync. AWS rejects those API calls.